# How can DWORD ever hold values more than 32 bits?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

The NSFDbSpaceUsage function in the Lotus Notes C API is defined as:

STATUS LNPUBLIC NSFDbSpaceUsage(
    DBHANDLE  hDB,
    **DWORD** far *retAllocatedBytes,
    **DWORD** far *retFreeByes);

This function returns the number of bytes allocated and the number of bytes free in a specified database.

Reading SO and elsewhere, I understand that DWORD is associated with *unsigned long*, which is (usually) 32 bits.  What puzzles me is how the above function will ever return the size of a Domino database that is more than 2^32 bytes in size.  And in fact, my sample application never returns anything greater than 2,147,483,647 (2^31) for some of my larger databases.  An NSF file in Domino can grow to 64 GB, so why would IBM use a DWORD to report the number of bytes allocated, when a DWORD can't represent more than 4,294,967,296 (2^32) bytes?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing this API method was created back when 4 GBs was larger than anyone could ever imagine ;)

According to the [comments here](http://www.cubert.net/2009/11/sntt-tracking-down-space-hogs-in-notes.html), this method is limited to only 4 GBs and there is another method to use: [NSFDbSpaceUsageScaled](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/tools/c/6.0.2/api60ref.nsf/0/3F822192B2597C7B852568E1005B1992?OpenDocument)